# Multiple dex Errors in android studio

Tags: cordova, android-studio

I am trying to make an app using phonegap-androidstudio. when i try to run the index.html of phonegap it shows me 17 error and 0 warnings.

> ```
> Compilation completed with 17 errors and 0 warnings in 20s 798ms
> Error:Android Dex: [android] Unable to execute DX
> Error:Android Dex: [android] com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/cordova/AuthenticationToken;
> Error:Android Dex: [android] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:579)
> Error:Android Dex: [android] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:535)
> Error:Android Dex: [android] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:517)
> Error:Android Dex: [android] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:164)
> Error:Android Dex: [android] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
> Error:Android Dex: [android] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)
> Error:Android Dex: [android] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
> Error:Android Dex: [android] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
> Error:Android Dex: [android] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> Error:Android Dex: [android] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> Error:Android Dex: [android] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> Error:Android Dex: [android] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
> Error:Android Dex: [android] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.runDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:161)
> Error:Android Dex: [android] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.main(AndroidDxRunner.java:294)
> Error:Android Dex: [android] at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:130)
> ```

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

This error happens, if you/a plugin, tries to implement Google Services multiple times. Put this lines in the build.gradle (Module Android) file of the Android folder in your project:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services'
}
```